# Is there a tag for re-inventing the wheel for educational purposes?

Tags: discussion

Following on from this programmers question: [Is the phrase "never reinvent the wheel" suitable for students?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/143874/is-the-phrase-never-reinvent-the-wheel-suitable-for-students)

Is there a suitable tag for re-inventing the wheel in order to learn? I often find myself re-inventing the wheel in order to learn how it works.

From September, I expect to ask more of this type of question as I start my final (and only) year of university.

Comment: Sounds like a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) to me.

Comment: To downvoters: please clarify. You've just reminded me why I/newbies don't bother suggesting things on meta :/

Comment: @StuartBlackler Downvotes here mean "I disagree" or "No"

Comment: @StuartBlackler Because newbies haven't read the [FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)?

Answer (score 6):

There *was* a [dont-reinvent-the-wheel](/questions/tagged/dont-reinvent-the-wheel) tag, but that tag doesn't add any value (and it can't stand on its own to support a question) so it's been removed (painstakingly I might add) as part of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012

I would recommend *not* recreating this tag for the reasons specified in the post linked to above.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I don't use meta often so I missed this. Thanks

Comment: @StuartBlackler NP.

Answer (score 3):

> I often find myself re-inventing the wheel in order to learn how it
>   works.
>
> From September, I expect to ask more of this type of question as I
>   start my final (and only) year of university.

No need for a tag, just put appropriate text in your question to stave off the [otherwise-inevitable flood of comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108060/why-do-people-question-every-question). Eg:

> Why do I get compile error `ABC1234` at line 6 of my quicksort routine:
>
> ```
> code
> ```
>
> *(nb: I am aware of the existence of  `.Sort()` - I am writing quicksort myself for the
>   educational experience*