# If I pose a question and later learn the premise was wrong, is it best to edit the question or leave it?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, edits, questions

If I ask a question about a data structure saying 'I currently have data structure X, how do I do Y with it?' and someone answers with 'You actually have data structure Z, this is how you do Y with it', is it best to leave my original question and allow the correction of the premise to exist within the answers/comments? Or should I go about editing the question and its description to reflect the correct framing?

Edit: I really disagree with the closure of this question. It is not a duplicate to the ones listed. The question is about modifying the question title/body to correct any mistakes made by the OP, such that the question can be found by the relevant passerby. Ie, ignoring how such a mistake would be made, if a question is titled to be asking about a dolphin, but the body/question/answer is, correctly, really about a whale, should the OP modify the title so that people looking for whale answers would correctly come to the question? Rather than skipping over it since they think its about a dolphin?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the answer “Don't do that” an acceptable response to a “how do I” question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/331082/282094) or  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263672/282094

Comment: My question is not about whether the answer is valid or not. It is. In the example I gave, I erred in saying it was data structure X. That it was data structure Z instead, and Y was still accomplished, I'd say the answer is right. My question here is whether, after identifying these truths, should I edit the question to say that I am dealing with data structure Z? Or does this correction belong in the answer, with my initially flawed premise remaining in place?

Comment: See also [Exit strategies for "chameleon questions"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

Comment: @RobertLongson sort of but this question appears to be asking from the answerer's perspective. In my question here, I am the OP. I am wondering if my question should be edited to reflect the corrections or left in its original state, with all corrections/clarifications left to the comments/answers.

Comment: In this case the single answer provided is accepted as correct; there are no further iterations. Nothing more is needed from the answerer. It is just a question regarding clarity for future viewers of the question. The structure was indeed Z. Should the question be edited to be asking about this structure? Or should it be left misnamed within the question title and description?

Comment: An edit that you or anyone else makes to your question must be careful to not invalidate other existing answers, if there's just one answer you should coordinate (via a comment on their answer, or an edit) with them about the edit you made. It is correct to fix everything, it is wrong to cause something (an answer) to be broken. --- This is why it's best to check back in half an hour after posting, to respond to comments and edits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That you *misunderstood* and needed to be corrected might be useful for someone else in the same situation. Its worth looking at this from multiple perspectives.

That someone *else* might mistake X for Z and would find it.

Search engines would pick up the answer on how to do Y on Z so someone who is looking for how to do that would find it.

There's absolutely no value in 'fixing' the question to anyone.

It's also generally poor form to 'significantly' edit the question and invalidate the answers there. Edits should be fixes of spelling and grammar, information requests from comments adding to the original question and additional steps that might have been attempted (but failed) to resolve the problem.

Keeping the question in its original context, as such, is the right thing to do.